# How can I access object keys, where keys in 'category.0' format, in nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, object, key, key-value

I have query regarding how to access Object key and value in which Key is stored as:

```js
var object1 = {
name: 'Developer',
'category.0': 'student',
'category.1': 'back-end'
}
//console.log(object1);
```

Is there any way to get category data as **category: '['student','back-end']'** OR **category: ['student','back-end']**

Or Is there any way to access Key **'category.0', 'category.1', ... 'category.n'**?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Go for `Object.keys(object1).forEach(el => console.log(el));` It will give you array of key and iterate over it.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara, Yes It will give me list of categories but I do have to check it as statice value for comparing. Where I have dynamic values for each

Comment: I didn't quite follow it can you add an example in your question code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your object with

```js
object1['category.0'];

// or

object1['category.' + n]
```

Where **n** is your number